# how to echo subarray of array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

i have array

```
$array= Array(
    'A' => Array
        (
            1 =>'foo',
            2=>Array(
                'a'=>'bar'
                )
                ),
          'B' =>'baz'
```

i want to print 
`'a'=>'bar'` this subarray.

Comment: What is your attempt to print that array?

Comment: `print($array['A'][2]['a']);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

`print_r($array['A'][2]);`

Comment: ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'print' (T_PRINT) in D:\wamp\www\sample.php on line 12 showing error